# Android: NeighboringCellInfo.getRssi() returning weird data for UMTS cells

Tags: android, ril, umts

According to the Android developer documentation, `NeighboringCellInfo.getRssi()` is specified as follows:

> received signal strength or UNKNOWN_RSSI if unknown For GSM, it is in "asu" ranging from 0 to 31 (dBm = -113 + 2*asu) 0 means "-113 dBm or less" and 31 means "-51 dBm or greater" For UMTS, it is the Level index of CPICH RSCP defined in TS 25.125

Some research revealed that this is probably a typo and should in fact refer to TS 25.133 section 9.1.1.3 (http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/25133.htm). Version 10.2.0 of that document essentially states that `CPICH_RSCP_LEV_-04` corresponds to `-120 dBm <= CPICH RSCP < -119 dBm` and so on, thus the signal level in dBm is obtained by subtracting 116 from the reported level.

The reporting range is from -120 to -25 dBm, which corresponds to levels -5 to +91.

However, in practice I notice that the values returned are way outside that range. I am seeing `getRssi()` returning values around -100. I suspect that the function is not returning **levels** as specified in the document, but **dBm**.

Has anyone else come across this and can confirm that Android indeed returns dBm rather than a signal level? Or is this an issue with the device used in the tests (a OnePlus One running Cyanogenmod 11 m11 – the community version, not the stock Cyanogenmod 11S with which the phone ships)?